# Apollo Server 4.0 Running Inside of Docker can't Connect With Redis Cache on Localhost

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, apollo

My goal is to run an Apollo Graph 4.0 Subscription server on AWS Fargate that uses AWS Redis Cache Service. Once I can get this configuration running locally I plan to migrate it to AWS.
These steps are all on my local machine:

1. I installed Redis locally, localhost:6379.
2. I ping redis to confirm that it is running. I receive a 'pong' message, which confirms it is running correctly.
3. I built then run my Apollo Server 4.0 in the terminal it connects to Redis and functions correctly. To this point all works correctly.
4. I created a docker image that holds the Apollo Graph server and run it.
   Create Docker Image: $ docker build -t apollo-server .
   I've run the Docker image with the following commands:

```
$ docker run --network host  apollo-server
$ docker run --network host -p 6379:6379  apollo-server
$ docker run --network host -p 4500:4500  apollo-server
```

5. The Apollo Graph server receives, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379, error upon start up.

My Dockerfile :

```
    FROM node:16-alpine

    ENV NODE_ENV=development

    WORKDIR /src

    COPY package*.json ./

    RUN npm install

    COPY . .

    EXPOSE 4500

    CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My Apollo Graph 4.0 Server:

```
import Keyv from "keyv";
import { KeyvAdapter } from "@apollo/utils.keyvadapter";

const isLocal = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'; 

const redisUrl = isLocal ? 'redis://localhost:6379' : 'redis://xxx:xxxxx@cacheforsubscriptionserver-sl5gpo.serverless.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379';
const keyv = new Keyv(redisUrl);

import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
//These are for express server
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';

import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';

import { resolvers }  from './resolvers.js';
import { typeDefs }   from './schema.js';
import { connect }    from './utils.js';

// Keep as part of DB access
import { UserAPI }      from './database/users.js';
import { SNSWriterAPI } from './AWSServices/SNSWriter.js';

const knex = connect();

  interface MyContext {
    token?: String;
    dataSources: {
      userApi               : UserAPI;
      SNSWriterAPI          : SNSWriterAPI;
    };
  }

  const app = express();
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

  // Set up Apollo Server.
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    cache:  new KeyvAdapter(keyv),
    plugins: [
      // Proper shutdown for the HTTP server.
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),

      // Proper shutdown for the WebSocket server.
      {
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              await serverCleanup.dispose();
            },
          };
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  // Creating the WebSocket server
  const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    path: '/subscription', 
  });


  /**
   * @param ctx - connection parameters; headers
   * @param msg 
   * @param args 
   * @returns 
   */
  const getDynamicContext = async (ctx, msg, args) => {
    let user = new UserAPI(knex);
    return  await user.getUser(ctx.connectionParams.emailAddress);
  };

  // Hand in the schema we just created and have the
  // WebSocketServer start listening.
  const serverCleanup = useServer(
    { schema,
      context: async (ctx, msg, args) => {
        // Returning an object will add that information to
        // contextValue, which all of our resolvers have access to.
        return await getDynamicContext(ctx, msg, args);
      }, 
    }, wsServer);

  await server.start();

app.use(
  '/',
  cors<cors.CorsRequest>(),
  bodyParser.json(),
  // expressMiddleware accepts the same arguments:
  // an Apollo Server instance and optional configuration options
  expressMiddleware(server, {
    context: async ({ req }) => ({ 
      Authorization: getToken(req.headers.Authorization),
      headers: req.headers,
      dataSources: {
        userApi     : new UserAPI(knex),
        SNSWriterAPI:  new SNSWriterAPI(),
      },
     }),
  }),
);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4500;
  
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
});
app.get('/health', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Okay!');
});
function getToken(authentication: string | string[]): String {
  const username = Array.isArray(authentication) ? authentication[0] : authentication;
  return username;
}
```

The following is the full error message:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 6379
}

Comment: What is your host OS; are you using Docker Desktop?  Host networking largely doesn't work on Docker Desktop, and 127.0.0.1 won't reach non-container processes there.  It also won't be an option in Fargate and isn't usually necessary.  I'd look into approaches to make this work that don't require `--network host`.

Comment: I am using MacOS running Docker Desktop. Is it Docker Engine that I should be using? I will investigate how to install and use Docker Engine. Do you know if it is suggested to uninstall Docker Desktop prior to installing Docker Engine?

What is an approach that would make this work and not require --network host?

Comment: If you have a MacOS host, you have to use Docker Desktop or another similar VM-based solution.  Are you trying to figure out, [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: I will work through the examples in that post but another question. When I migrate to AWS to use Fargate will or won't I be able to use Docker Desktop. The Fargate AMI will be Linux so I expect I won't. Therefore, the Docker Desktop solution is not ultimately what I need. What I really need to do is to run this in the AWS environment using Docker Engine. Is that correct?

Comment: I think that's a little secondary to the question you're asking here.  If you're using an AWS Elasticache instance for Redis, you'd use that service's DNS name, regardless of the container environment you're using (if any).

Comment: Still have the problem running on my local machine. Given my goal is to run within AWS, I am not going to continue to try to solve the local container issue. As even if I solve it I will not be using Docker Desktop in AWS. I'm moving the code to an EC2 and will build the container there.